# How do I run multiple lines of Ruby in html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, block, erb

I'm using Ruby on Rails and need to run a block of Ruby code in one of my html.erb files. Do I do it like this:

```
<% def name %>
<% name = username %>
<%= name %>
```

or like this:

```
<% def name
name = username %>
<%= name %>
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Why are you trying to create a function in a view? It belongs most likely into the model, or if not into the controller, but definitely not into the view

Comment: Sorry, I just quickly typed some code in there as an example.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is unusual to define a method in an ERB file, so I recommend against it.

If you want to call a block like `#each`, you can do something like the following:

```
<% names.each do |name| %>
  <%= name %>
<% end %>
```

Don't forget the `<% end %>`.

Answer (score 42):

If you need extra functions in your view, you normally declare those inside a helper.

For each controller, if there is a helper it is automatically loaded. For instance, if you have a PeopleController, in the `app/helpers` folder, there should be a `people_helper.rb`, and it should look like this

```
module PeopleHelper
  def name
    #do something
    username
  end
end
```

Another, very clean alternative, is to use the [Presenter](http://www.subelsky.com/2008/01/presenter-classes-help-with-rails.html) [pattern](http://www.google.com/search?q=rails+presenter), but i think it is less common (unfortunately).

Otherwise, if you do need multiple lines of ruby code inside a erb view, which i try to avoid, i prefer the following style:

```
<%
   counter_1 = 0
   counter_2 = 1
   do_some_more_prep_here
 %>
<% @records.each do |rec|%>
  <%# do something with the prepped date in each row %>
<% end %>
```

Also for me code indentation is more important than html indentation, so i will prefer something like

```
<table> 
  <% @rows.each do |row| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= row.item1 %></td>
      <% if row.some_test %>
        <td><%= row.item2 %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

But i am always very interested to hear different opinions in this matter.

Comment: Helper methods are the way to go, for sure.

Comment: How would you go about using the PeopleHelper name method in the html.erb?

Comment: Any method declared in a helper should just be available in the views (so with that in mind I would prefer a bit more specific method-name now, looking back). Is that not the case for you?

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine someone needing it in one particular template (no point in creating a helper) to not duplicate html markup. That is, when resulting html page has a couple of similar blocks of html markup. Though, it can easily be abused (unreadable code).

```
<% def f1(a, b, c) %>
  test: <%= a %>, <%= b %>, <%= c %>
<% end %>

<% f1(1, 2, 3) %>
<% f1(4, 5, 6) %>
```

Comment: your answer doesn't work, all it is doing is putting the contents of the function on a webpage, treating it as HTML not as rails or ruby code https://i.imgur.com/rhTNtt5.png

Comment: @barlop Sorry for being unelaborate. Check out my answer. Does that work for you? That's probably what I meant.

Comment: that displays `test: ,,,`   because your code has `<%` and not `<%=` But this works https://i.imgur.com/Gtytbg9.png  So you might want to correct your answer and you should really have tested it before posting it.

Comment: @barlop I'm not sure where I get that idea. But I assure you I tested it. Maybe it worked with the other version of Rails or `erb` gem. The problem is that I wasn't elaborate enough. Does my current solution work for you?